# Stuck at grub rescue after installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.10, windows-8, grubrescue

I tried installing Ubuntu 13.10 next to Windows 8 on my laptop, but it was booting straight into Windows 8 all the time.

I executed a boot repair from a live USB and since then I'm getting a nice black screen with `grub rescue>`.

[Here is the URL](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6885441/) boot repair gave me.

I know which of my partitions is the Linux one on my disk; I can read what is on it in the GRUB rescue command line with `ls (hd0,gpt5)/`.

That's pretty much all that I can do! (I'm a beginner with Linux and I can't access the BIOS to modify any setup for the moment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally fixed it this way:

1. I was fortunate to be able to boot on a live cd.
2. I saved important documents I needed from my partitions.
3. Then with GParted I deleted all the crap (multiple partitions of Windows 8...)
4. Finally I installed Windows 7 (I don't know why this version is getting along better with Linux) and Linux.

Hope it can help other people!